# Data to test optimization algorithms

Tags: optimization, python

I plan to implement some optimization algorithms in Python, say to follow the sequence [here](http://www.scientificpython.net/uploads/1/1/5/9/11598566/lecturenotes1.pdf) or [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387303030).

What would be a systematic approach to testing the algorithms I write, using either well-known test datasets or creating my own?

Comment: You've seen [this](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/glopt/test.html)?

Comment: See also http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/testing-numerical-optimization-methods-rosenbrock-vs-real-test-functions and http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/46/where-can-one-obtain-good-data-sets-test-problems-for-testing-algorithms-routine.

Comment: @J.M. 404 not found